# CHRE nanoapp in dragonboard

Tags: android-source, dragonboard

I'm working on a project involving AOSP Android and CHRE nanoapp creation. I've successfully built AOSP (13) for the development board Dragonboard845. Next planning to create nano app in CHRE. please help me to start the dev. I am new in this area. I have tried to clone from refs/heads/android10-chre-dev - platform/system/chre - Git at Google.

But getting lot of error during compilation.

CHRE compilation Issue